# how return true or false in a method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos, methods, return

I need to find a key in a hash then return true if this key already exist or false if doesn't exist but for some reason I have an error in the terminal.
this is my method:

```
def key_no_exist (hash,key)
hash.each do |clave,valor|
  if clave == key
    return false
  end
end
 return true
```

end

and after I use that return in this code:

```
        when "set"
        key = sep[1] #string who contain my key
        client.puts "SEND DATABLOCK:  "
        resp = client.gets.chomp
        datablock = resp.scan(/\w+/)
        if key_no_exist(data,key) #if the key doesn't exist, add the data block into the hash
          data[:key] = datablock
          client.puts"STORED: \r\n "
        else
          client.puts "CLIENT_ERROR [key already exists]\r\n"
        end
```

**by after all when I running the code in the terminal I this problem:
:22: warning: assigned but unused variable - data**

**:75: warning: parentheses after method name is interpreted as an argument list, not a decomposed argument**

**in `block (2 levels) in run':undefined local variable or method` data' for #Server:0x00007fdd0695d8d8 (NameError)**

firstable I create a hash named data:

```
class Server
def initialize(port,ip)
  @server = TCPServer.open(ip,port)
  @connections = Hash.new
  @clients = Hash.new
  @connections[:server] = @server
  @connections[:clients] = @clients
  data = Hash.new

  run
end
```

Comment: Why not just use [`has_key?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the method declaration syntax and method calling syntax. Your method declaration `def key_no_exist(data,key)` is fine, this method expects two arguments, the first is the hash, the second is the key. When you then call this method, you need to pass in the actual hash, and the actual key you are checking. I am not sure which of your variables (`client` or `resp` or something else) is the hash, but say its called `your_hash`, you will call this method like`if key_no_exist(your_hash, key)`.

The error you are getting `undefined local variable or method data` is saying there is no variable called `data`, ie there is no `data = something`.

As for the actual method you are using, ruby comes with a hash method `.has_key?` which returns true if the key is there, else returns false. So instead of writing your own method, you could just do something like `if your_hash.has_key?(key)`.